# How to change Primary DNS Suffix of a computer in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wmi

I'm working on an auto-configure app for new PC's. I managed to programatically set all the needed parameters, except Primary DNS Suffix of a computer (please remember that this is different from the network connection default DNS suffix).

Any help?

Update: Here's requested class for setting IP, Subnet, Gateway, and DNS of the PC.
http://pastebin.com/fHACwwDV

It was tested only in system having 1 network interface, I don't know how it'll behave when there are more NICs. Oh, and it's WIP, so for now no error handling apart from throwing exception was implemented.

Comment: Can you please add documentation links that shows have you have done all other configurations? Really useful information for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a search on msdn, looks like you'll need to use [SetComputerNameEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724931%28VS.85%29.aspx).

[pinvoke.net spells out what you'll need to do to access this from C#.](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/SetComputerNameEx.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yay, it worked. Of course I'm stupid as always, because I was already setting the host name.
Here's full code for host/suffix change in vb.net:

```
Private Enum COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT As Integer
    ComputerNameNetBIOS = 0
    ComputerNameDnsHostname = 1
    ComputerNameDnsDomain = 2
    ComputerNameDnsFullyQualified = 3
    ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS = 4
    ComputerNamePhysicalDnsHostname = 5
    ComputerNamePhysicalDnsDomain = 6
    ComputerNamePhysicalDnsFullyQualified = 7
End Enum

Public Const MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH As Int32 = 31

<DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function SetComputerNameEx( _
    ByVal NameType As COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT, _
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Integer
End Function

Public Function SetNewName(ByVal Computername As String, ByVal DNSSuffix As String) As Boolean
    If NetworkSet.SetComputerNameEx(COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT.ComputerNamePhysicalDnsHostname, _
        Computername & Convert.ToChar(0)) = 0 Then
        Throw New Win32Exception
    End If
    If NetworkSet.SetComputerNameEx(COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT.ComputerNamePhysicalDnsDomain, _
        DNSSuffix & Convert.ToChar(0)) = 0 Then
        Throw New Win32Exception
    End If

End Function
```